# How to make array into array list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

from this array

```
s = np.array([[35788, 41715, ... 34964], 
          [5047, 23529, ... 5165], 
          [12104, 33899, ... 11914], 
          [3646, 21031, ... 3814], 
          [8704, 7906, ... 8705]])
```

I have a loop like this

```
end =[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i, len(s)):
        out = mahalanobis(s[i], s[j], invcov)       
        end.append(out)
print end
```

and i take output :

```
[0.0, 12.99, 5.85, 10.22, 3.95, 0.0, 5.12, 3.45, 4.10, 0.0, 5.05, 8.10, 0.0, 15.45, 0.0]
```

but I want the output like this :

```
[[0.0, 12.99, 5.85, 10.22, 3.95], 
[12.99, 0.0, 5.12, 3.45, 4.10], 
[5.85, 5.12, 0.0, 5.05, 8.10], 
[10.22, 3.45, 5.05, 0.0, 15.45], 
[3.95, 4.10, 8.10, 15.45, 0.0]]
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a list containing lists of exactly 5 items each?  Or will the size of the inside lists vary?

Comment: I want a list containing lists of exactly 5 items each, like a distance matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the list,

```
end = [0.0, 12.99, 5.85, 10.22, 3.95, 0.0, 5.12, 3.45, 4.10, 0.0, 5.05, 8.10, 0.0, 15.45, 0.0]
```

you could build the desired 2-dimensional array using

```
import numpy as np
result = np.zeros((s.shape[0],)*2)               # 1
result[np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 0)] = end     # 2
result += result.T                               # 3
print(result)
```

which yields

```
[[  0.    12.99   5.85  10.22   3.95]
 [ 12.99   0.     5.12   3.45   4.1 ]
 [  5.85   5.12   0.     5.05   8.1 ]
 [ 10.22   3.45   5.05   0.    15.45]
 [  3.95   4.1    8.1   15.45   0.  ]]
```

1. make an array filled with zeros
2. [`np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) returns the indices for the upper-triangle of an array of shape `(s.shape[0], s.shape[0])`.

   ```
   In [95]: np.triu_indices(5, 0)
   Out[95]: 
   (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]),
    array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]))
   ```

   `result[...] = end` fills the upper-triangle with the values from `end`.
3. Take the transpose of `result` and add that to `result`, thus making `result` symmetric.

This allows you to obtain the result without calling both `mahalanobis(s[i], s[j])` and `mahalanobis(s[j], s[i])` which is unnecessary since `mahalanbis` distance is symmetric.

---

Note that the diagonal is always zero since `mahalanobis(x,x)` equals zero for
any `x`. So for a little added efficiency, you could exclude the diagonal:

```
end =[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):              # <-- note i+1
        out = mahalanobis(s[i], s[j], invcov)       
        end.append(out)
```

and then build `result` with the same code as before except that now we can use

```
result[np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 1)] = end
```

instead of

```
result[np.triu_indices(s.shape[0], 0)] = end
```

The second argument to `np.triu_indices` controls the diagonal offset. When the offset is 1, the indices corresponding the the main diagonal are omitted.

```
In [96]: np.triu_indices(5, 1)
Out[96]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]))
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to loop differently in at least **two** ways:

```
end =[]
for s1 in s:
    end.append([mahalanobis(s1, s2, invcov) for s2 in s])
```

The most important thing is that the inner loop needs to be on the whole `s` again, else you will never get a square but `1 + 2 + ... + len(s)` items (15 in this case as `len(s)` is 5).

Next, the inner loop must be enclosed in a list, since you want a list of lists.

Less important but nice: I've changed the inner loop to a list comprehension; and I've changed both loops to be directly on `s` since there's really no reason to go over the indirection of looping over indices then using those indices to get the `s` items you **care** about.

So I made four changes in all, but the first two are what you really need to get the result you desire, the other two are just nice improvements:-).

Comment: nice and compact, but how would you assure there that you have 5 elements in the inner array? when i run your code i get different array length depending on input, and i thought Majesty wanted 5 fix?

Comment: You'll have just as many items in each sub-list as you have sub-lists -- "like a distance matrix" (the distance matrix among N points is of course always a square matrix, N by N).

Answer (score 0):

your loop is fine, if you just add a counter and a second array, then you can group results in groups of 5 elements in one array (if this is the desired result)

```
end =[]
tmp =[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i, len(s)):
        out = mahalanobis(s[i], s[j], invcov)
        if k % 5 == 0 and k != 0:
            end.append(tmp)
            tmp =[]       
        k += 1
        tmp.append(out)
if len(tmp) > 0:
    end.append(tmp)
print end
```

No matter what your input then, your output will be an array with n arrays each with 5 members `[[1,2,3,4,5],[...],[...], ... ]`

Comment: You missed the most important error in that `range(i, len(s))` -- generating fewer and fewer items each time through.  With len(s) at 5 this makes a three by five matrix, **not** the 5 by 5 declared as the desired output in the body of the question.

Comment: @AlexMartelli yupp, i just concentrated on the 5 array business, as Majesty had not posted the sample data until i had posted my answer... i prefer yours anyhow from style and if the result is what was desired, then perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use your code, and underneath it:

```
end2 = []
for repeat in range(len(end)/5-1):
    end2.append(end[0:4])
    end = end[5:]
```

Comment: `end` as generated by the Q's posted code is only 15 items long (not 25) so this will have plenty of empties at the tail of `end2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward iteration that allocates the elements of `out` to a symmetric matrix:

```
x=np.zeros((5,5))
cnt=0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i,5):
        x[j,i] =x[i,j] = out[cnt]
        cnt += 1
```

producing

```
array([[  0.  ,  12.99,   5.85,  10.22,   3.95],
       [ 12.99,   0.  ,   5.12,   3.45,   4.1 ],
       [  5.85,   5.12,   0.  ,   5.05,   8.1 ],
       [ 10.22,   3.45,   5.05,   0.  ,  15.45],
       [  3.95,   4.1 ,   8.1 ,  15.45,   0.  ]])
```

Since this iteration parallels your original one, you could construct the matrix right away:

```
n = s.shape[0]
x = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        x[i,j] = x[j,i] = mahalanobis(s[i], s[j], invcov)       
print x
```

I use `i+1` in inner loop since, apparently, `mahalanobis` is 0 for `i==j`.